# Django - dynamic fields in Admin form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to make some advanced customization of Django admin form.

While editing an object, I want to show, dynamically, different fields depending of 1 obj field (they are not visible while adding the obj.). There can be a situation, to validate that extra fields. For example, when object has a 'temporary' type, I must show 2 fields with dates, and validate them. If object is 'renewable' I need to show 2 different fields with different validation. I've searched a lot of pages, but nowhere found 1 strict method.

What is the best approach to do that?

- Make separate `Form` for each object type and set form attrib of `ModelAdmin`? If yes, in which `ModelAdmin` method do that (`change_view()`?)?
- Dynamically update [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields) in `get_form()` method?

What is the best approach to do that?

Comment: Why don't you try it using ajax and jQuery? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15082166/1095090

Comment: Because I have to do that in Form level, not frontend level. For me, it's not a good solution, because in some time, there will be some more complex form.